# Search textbox show elements over the textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use this [searchbox](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default). Everything is ok, but I want that searchbox to show elements over the searchbox and not under the searchbox. I was looking in css and js files, but I couldn´t find it.

Comment: can you correct your english? what exactly you mean?

Comment: I want that available tags were showing over the input. Now were showing under the input. Now do you understand?

Comment: yes now i understand? is it possible for you to put up fiddle for it?

Comment: Yes sure, there is it :
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/y8TX6/)

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/y8TX6/13/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [From jQueryUI API Docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-position)

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({ 
    position: { 
        my: "center bottom", 
        at: "center top" 
    } 
});
```

*(obviously add the rest of your code here as usual - only thing you need is the position info)*

## [Example in a fiddle diddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VXH6H/)

Comment: Work it is what I do.  Glad to help.